# Why Python's list structure store the PyObject using **ob_item instead of *ob_item

Tags: python, c

Python's list structure is like below:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    PyObject **ob_item;
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

Why using **ob_item? I think *ob_item is enough.

Comment: Are you under the impression that the list's storage physically contains its elements, like a C++ vector or something? The list just holds pointers to its elements.

Answer (score 2):

Because, as with any list created using pointers, as you add and remove elements, you'll need to change *what a node's pointer is pointing to*, not just the value of the object being pointed to (which is what you would get with just `*ob_item`; `**ob_item` let's you "repoint" the pointer).

Remember, the list is not going to contain the actual objects, it contains pointers to them. To be able to use a pointer that points to a pointer (to, as I mentioned, be able to repoint the pointer for a node), you need `**`.